# What could be the problem with the javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I have the below script which is failing to return the right condition (**TRUE**). What could be the problem?

```js
var momo_no = 0759933091;
if (momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 075 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 070 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 074 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 077 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 078 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 076 || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != 039) {
  alert('FALSE');
} else {
  alert('TRUE');
}
```

Comment: Many things. Firstly, you have octal numbers here except for 039, which is probably not intended. I guess you want strings, so quote them. Secondly, your input also isn't a string, so it won't have a `substring` method. Again, quote it. Thirdly, you check whether it's not 075 or not 070 or not 074 etc. and then you alert "FALSE", however that would hold true for _any_ value whatsoever, because the "or" should be "and" (if I have an apple and I ask "is this not an apple **or** not an orange?" the answer will be "yes" as it's not an orange). Fourthly, it can be simplified with switch or include.

Comment: You can try converting `momo_no` to String, and then use `.substring()`. You will also have to change the comparisons, e.g. `momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "075"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single number cannot be equal to multiple values at the same time, so try this code but with &&, hope it helps:

```
var momo_no = "0759933091";
if (
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "075" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "070" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "074" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "077" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "078" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "076" &&
  momo_no.substring(0, 3) !== "039"
) {
  alert("FALSE");
} else {
  alert("TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The substing function will not work int values. It will only work with string. Try below code, it will work properly.

```
var momo_no = "0759933091";
if (momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "075" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "070" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "074" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "077" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "078" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "076" || momo_no.substring(0, 3) != "039") {
  alert('FALSE');
} else {
  alert('TRUE');
}
```

Comment: This will remove the leading 0 and therefore does not give the desired output

Comment: Correct it will remove zero in this case. In this case number should be string.